# split the array into sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of mobilenumbers, it contains 9000 numbers or sometimes more.

I want to split this array to sub arrays, each array should have 3000 numbers only and pass them to a function:

```
function sendSMS($mobilenumbers){

//some code here

}
```

Thank you

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "gimme code" kind of site...what have you tried so far? Where are your problems?

Comment: And a example of your array structure ;)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: You can try  array_slice() here you can specify

Comment: [googling for your question title will yield the appropriate function as the first result](https://www.google.de/search?q=split+the+array+into+sub+arrays). Please do research before asking questions, like you agreed to do in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php 

    $array_of_numbers = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
    $smaller_array_of_numbers = array_chunk($array_of_numbers, 3000);

    foreach($smaller_array_of_numbers as $smaller_array){
        sendSMS($smaller_array);
    }

?>
```

The function [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) is key here.

What this'll do is use `array_chunk` to split the array into smaller arrays, then using a simple foreach loop it'll loop around these smaller arrays and send them to the `sendSMS` function.

Answer (score 6):

Try this :

```
$aray_number = your input array;
$array       = array_chunk($aray_number,3000);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php